# Firebase error: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, vercel

I'm facing an annoying problem with my next js app with firebase. So far in localhost it was all fine, I can read and write normally. I deployed it to vercel, but it can't reach my firebase database. I get the following error:

Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project.This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I have searched about it and all I got was to set my rules in firebase so it is readable and writable, but it's been right the whole time:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

(it's a university project, so I don't have any authentication).

My environment variables are also set right in vercel (confirmed because the error shows the firebase project name, which is encrypted in vercel)

Also, I found something about setting experimentalForceLongPolling, as in this:

```
const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
});
```

but I'm using firebase v10.6, so the syntax has changed, as well as this parameter.

I really don't have a clue of what's wrong

Comment: Where are you seeing this error: in your vercel server logs or in the browser JS console?  Are you using the Firebase Client SDK or the Firebase Admin SDK?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Greg asked for, and please also respond using @.